# Pass a function return to another in the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, alias

I Need to pass the return value of a function that is selected in previous column and pass it as parameter to a following function in the same row. I cannot use the alias:

What I want to have is:

```
SELECT
    dbo.GetSecondID(f.ID) as SecondID,
    dbo.GetThirdID(SecondID) as ThirdID
FROM Foo f
```

Any workaround? Thank you!

**EDIT:**

The method `dbo.GetSecondID()` is very heavy and I am dealing with a couple of million records in the table. It is not wise to pass the method as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bingo! The secret stand in applying a `CROSS APPLY`. The following code was helpful

```
SELECT
    sndID.SecondID,
    dbo.GetThirdID(sndID.SecondID) as ThirdID
FROM Foo f
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT dbo.GetSecondID(f.ID) as SecondID
) sndID
```

**EDIT:**

This only works if `SecondID` is unique (only one record is returned) or `GROUP BY` is used

Answer (score 3):

The way that SQL is designed, it is intended that all columns can be computed in parallel (in theory). This means that you *cannot* have one column's value depend on the result of computing a different column (within the same `SELECT` clause).

To be able to reference the column, you might introduce a subquery:

```
SELECT SecondID,dbo.GetThirdID(SecondID) as ThirdID
FROM
(
    SELECT
        dbo.GetSecondID(f.ID) as SecondID   
    FROM Foo f
) t
```

or a CTE:

```
;WITH Results1 AS (
    SELECT
        dbo.GetSecondID(f.ID) as SecondID   
    FROM Foo f
)
SELECT SecondID,dbo.GetThirdID(SecondID) as ThirdID
FROM Results1
```

If you're building up calculations multiple times (e.g. A depends on B, B depends on C, C depends on D...), then the CTE form usually ends up looking neater (IMO).

Comment: Thanks for this. Since `Results1` will actually execute for all rows, I will have to include the "not at all complex" `WHERE` clause both in the query and the sub-query. `CROSS APPLY` will actually use the same filter. THANK YOU for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this:

```
SELECT
     dbo.GetThirdID(dbo.GetSecondID(f.ID)) as ThirdID
FROM Foo f
```