# How do i can show forecast years data from row into column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, common-table-expression

Suppose if Item-A's Sale in 2013 is 100 Quantity and I'm expecting 10% of sales growth in next year i.e. in 2014

```
--------------------
 ITEM | YEAR | QTY | 
--------------------
 ITM-A| 2013 | 100 |
 ITM-B| 2013 | 200 |
--------------------
```

if I want to forecast sale data for up to year 2015

```
------------------------------
   Item | 2013 | 2014 | 2015 | 
------------------------------ 
 Item-A | 100  | 110  | 121  |--each year qty incremented by 10% of its
 Item-B | 200  | 220  | 242  |--previous year qty
------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,you have to use dynamic sql

```
Declare @toyear int=2016
Declare @forcast int=10
Declare @t table (ITEM varchar(50), years int, qty int)
insert into @t
select 'TM-A' ITEM , 2013 years, 100 qty
union all
select 'TM-B' ITEM , 2013 years, 200 qty

;with CTE1 as
(
select * from @t
union all
select b.ITEM,b.years+1,b.qty+((@forcast*b.qty)/100) from @t a 
inner join cte1 b on a.ITEM=b.ITEM 
and b.years<@toyear
)
    select * from
(select  * from cte1 )t4
pivot(min(qty) for years in([2013],[2014],[2015],[2016]))pvt
```

Comment: @KumarHarsh- Thanks buddy, U r Great... this is enough to solve my problem.. many more to do using this...

Comment: @RupeshS,Welcome ! You forgot to mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select item, 
       qty as '2013',
       round(qty*1.1) as '2014', 
       round(qty*1.21) as '2015' 
from sale;
```

A dynamic query using stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure p (IN end INT(10))
BEGIN
    declare start int;
    declare fact FLOAT;
    SET fact = 1.1;
    SELECT year into start FROM sale limit 1;
    SET @QUERY1 = CONCAT("SELECT ITEM, QTY AS '",start,"'"); 
    WHILE start < end DO
    SET start = start + 1;
        SET @QUERY1 = CONCAT(@QUERY1," ,qty*",fact," as '", start,"'");
        SET fact = fact *1.1; 
    END WHILE;
    SET @QUERY1 = CONCAT(@QUERY1," from sale");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @QUERY1;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END $$      

DELIMITER ;
```

Output:

```
mysql> call p(2016);
+-------+------+-------+--------+---------+
| ITEM  | 2013 | 2014  | 2015   | 2016    |
+-------+------+-------+--------+---------+
| itemA |  100 | 110.0 | 121.00 | 133.100 |
| itemB |  200 | 220.0 | 242.00 | 266.200 |
+-------+------+-------+--------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: good try... but not the solution
I want to generate column dyanamically

Comment: Bhai Nishant Thnks... i want to generate years as columns dynamically

Comment: Give me any recursive sulution for that

Answer (score 0):

Check this question:

[Pass a function return to another in the same row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307000/pass-a-function-return-to-another-in-the-same-row)

Your function is simply the multiplication by 1.1