# How do i can show forecast data in years from row into column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, common-table-expression

Suppose if Item-A's Sale in 2013 is 100 Quantity and I'm expecting 10% of sales growth in next year i.e. in 2014

```
--------------------
 ITEM | YEAR   | QTY | 
--------------------
 ITM-A| Jan 13 | 100 |
 ITM-B| Feb 13 | 200 |
--------------------
```

if I want to forecast sale data for up to year 2015

```
---------------------------------------------------
  Item  |Jan 13|Jan 14|Jan 15|Feb 13|Feb 14|Feb 15|  
--------------------------------------------------- 
 Item-A | 100  | 110  | 121  |  -   |  -   |  -   |--each year qty incrementd by 10% of
 Item-B |  -   |  -   |  -   | 200  | 220  | 242  |-- its previous year qty
---------------------------------------------------
```

All i wanted to generate columns dynamically

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i can show forecast years data from row into column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22198973/how-do-i-can-show-forecast-years-data-from-row-into-column)

Comment: it doesn't matter.. do you have solution over my problem that i posted above.. then tell me

Comment: The solution is the same (by @KumarHarsh) instead of YEARS you should use MONTH and YEARS.

Answer (score 0):

According to me create xml of your data and generate your html will be much faster. You can create a custom control and develop your report.

Comment: No need of this... i want solution in SQL only